# Is it possible to see the content of game updates on Steam?

Tags: steam

I have automatic game updates enabled on Steam, but so far I haven't been able to find an easy way to see exactly **what** has been updated.

Is there a way to see the details of a game update on Steam, similar to how you would do it on the Apple App Store or on Google Play?

Comment: It depends on the game developer if they make this information public or not. Even on app store or google play you often see details like "various improvements" which tells you nothing. I think steam opted for giving  developers an option of not putting in some bla instead of description when they have nothing to say.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: Arrow pointing to the View News link on the downloads area]

**Sometimes**. It depends on if the game has released information about what has been updated. Some games are really good about it, others are not.

To view where it would be, go to your downloads page (Library > Downloads) and where the download is, you should see a view news link on the right hand side of the page. This takes you to the Steam News page for that game, and is where games would be able to share what has changed with recent updates. If there is a lot of news and you just want the changes, you can filter on the *Product Updates* category to see only items that notes changes made.

[image: Image showing the Product Updates category filter on the Steam Game News pages]

Note some games may use an external site or system for reporting this information, but this is the most centralized place for Steam.

Comment: I would like to add that you can also access that page directly from the game entry in the library itself, on the right side, the link "News" under LINKS. Often, such updates are also on the storefront page of the game itself.

Comment: Also, some developers post the patch notes on in the Steam Forums, but I guess you can count this as an 'external system'.

Comment: I guess this is the best we can get at the moment, although the News section is often filled with all kind of news related to the game but with no mention of recent updates.

Comment: @user1301428 if you want to filter specifically to only see updates, you can use the "Product Updates" channel filter on the right hand side.